# How to return the array in html with groupBy() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, functional-programming

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/r8zt1wya/76/)

I am going through this tutorial:
https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/

And I am basically trying to display the new grouped array in a div, but I get two objects no matter what array I use with the function.

When I try to display the result in HTML I get two objects:

```
groupedByLocation: [object Object]
```

I should get this list:

```
groupedByLocation = {
    mall: [
      { time: '9:00', location: 'mall' },
      { time: '12:00', location: 'mall' },
    ],
    store: [
      { time: '9:00', location: 'store' },
      { time: '12:00', location: 'store' },
    ],
    market: [
      { time: '12:00', location: 'market' },
    ],
  }
```

All the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>JSON Test</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div id="myData"></div>

   </body>

 </html>

const events = [{
    time: '12:00',
    location: 'mall'
  },
  {
    time: '9:00',
    location: 'store'
  },
  {
    time: '9:00',
    location: 'mall'
  },
  {
    time: '12:00',
    location: 'store'
  },
  {
    time: '12:00',
    location: 'market'
  },
]

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    const val = item[prop]
    groups[val] = groups[val] || []
    groups[val].push(item)
    return groups
  }, {})
}

const groupedByLocation = events.groupBy('location')
console.log('groupedByLocation' + groupedByLocation)

var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = 'groupedByLocation: ' + groupedByLocation;
mainContainer.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: `div.innerHTML = 'groupedByLocation: ' + JSON.stringify(groupedByLocation);`

Comment: As @raina77ow mentioned you have to convert the object to a string for the html to know how to render it (it can only render primitives). When it renders `[object Object]` that's not "2 objects", its an array of `object`s. The first `object` is the type

Comment: Thank you both. This has now been resolved.